# VBA: matching multiple strings

Tags: vba

MY question would best be understood be the following example, my goal is to classify the following string into category if the string matches any one of the strings defined in those categories. For example,

```
dim test_str as string

test_str = "tomato"
```

If the test string `tomato` matches any one of the keywords (1) `potato`, (2) `tomato` and (3) `spaghetti`, then tomato will be classified as food.

I have a very inefficient way of doing this now, which involves using multiple `strcomp`, i.e.

```
if(strcomp(test_str, "potato", vbtextcompare) = 0 or _
strcomp(test_str, "tomato", vbtextcompare) =0 or _ 
strcomp(test_str, "spaghetti", vbtextcompare)=0 ) then 
     'label test str as "food"
```

However, if I have 10 keywords defined within "food", I would then need 10 `strcomp` statements, which would be tedious. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply store all the combinations in a string and check that the value is present with `InStr`:

```
Const food = "|potato|tomato|spaghetti|"

Dim test_str As String
test_str = "tomato"

If InStr(1, food, "|" & test_str & "|", vbTextCompare) Then
  Debug.Print "food"
Else
  Debug.Print "not food"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that helps you

```
Function ArrayWordNotInText(textValue, arrayKeyword)
   Dim i
   ArrayWordNotInText = -1
   For i = LBound(arrayKeyword) To UBound(arrayKeyword)
      If Not StrComp(textValue, arrayKeyword(i), vbTextCompare) Then ArrayWordNotInText = i
   Next i
End Function
```

If the return value = -1 ... no Match, >0  the index of the word

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time posting; excuse my formatting. Have not been using VBA for too long but was able to piece this together.

```
  Sub vinden4()

  Dim EXCEPT() As String, a As Integer

  EM = "no.replynoreply@ziggo.nl"

  Exceptions = "no-Reply,noreply,nO.reply,"

        EXCEPT = Split(Exceptions, ",")
        For i = LBound(EXCEPT) To UBound(EXCEPT)            

NOREPLY = InStr(1, EM, EXCEPT(i), vbTextCompare)

If NOREPLY > 0 Then
'CbEM.Value = True '~food~
EM = InputBox("NOREPLY E-MAILADRES", "Geef E-mailadres aan", EM)
'else
'CbEM.Value = False ~not food~
End If

        Next i

MsgBox EM

End Sub
```

Hope this can help someone.